# Find a basis for a set involving complex conjugates

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

How can I find a basis for this vector space over ℝ:

A={(u, v, v̄, -u) : u,v ∈ }
(so u and v are complex numbers of the form a + bi and v̄ is the complex conjugate of v).

It's just the complex conjugate part which is confusing me and I can't find any other examples of it online. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Seems 2-dimensional.

Comment: If you are thinking of that as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^4$ I think it's not. $(0,i, -i, 0) \in A$ but $i$ times that vector is not.

Comment: I forgot to include over the reals in my original post. I've edited to clarify this

Comment: You do realize that A wouldn’t even be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ right? Your clarification doesn’t make sense

Comment: Yup, you're right, A isn't a subset of ℝ^4. However, what we have here is a set over the Real field, but with complex entries